# Encrypt exisiting database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, encryption

I have an app already published in Play Store. Now, I want to encrypt the database of the app.

I know about SQLCipher for Android which can do this for me. But the problem is that my app is already used by a lot of users and they have lots of unencrypted data inside it.

Now, how can I use SQLCipher with an existing unencrypted database? So that all my previous data gets encrypted without any problem and new data gets going as it should.

Comment: SQLCipher is an SQLite extension that provides transparent 256-bit AES encryption of database files...  link  -- https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/

Comment: You have to provide an upgrade script but yes AFAIK you can upgrade an existing database. Have you tried?

Comment: @shkschneider I couldn't get you? Can you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt a plaintext database using SqlCipher using the following commands or alternatively you can find Java example code on [GitHub](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/net/zetetic/tests/ImportUnencryptedDatabaseTest.java).

```
$ ./sqlcipher plaintext.db
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.db' AS encrypted KEY 'testkey';
sqlite> SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');
sqlite> DETACH DATABASE encrypted;
```

You can encrypt the user's database as part of the installation of your new app by overriding the onUpgrade method in your installer.

Comment: Thanks for it. Should I encrypt the my original database only once after the user updates the app?

Comment: You can add logic to your app that checks if the user database is encrypted and then encrypt if it is not.

Comment: Thats a good idea. But is there a way to check if my database is encrypted and then only encrypt it?

Comment: The link has expired!